# how to call the method one class to another class in obj c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have one appdelegate and notifyviewcontroller class.

declare one method `-(void)getNotificaionform in notifyviewcontroller`.

I want to call this method in `appdelegate applicationDidBecomeActive` and `applicationDidEnterBackground` .

How can i achieve this help me?

I'm new to development.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling UIViewController method from app delegate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950670/calling-uiviewcontroller-method-from-app-delegate)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIViewController * vc in Nvc.viewControllers) {
    if ([vc isKindOfClass:notifyviewcontroller Class]) {
        [vc getNotificaionform];
    }
}
```

Use this code in your applicationDidEnterBackground and Here Nvc is an object of UINavigationController .

Answer (score 0):

For you **appDelegate** to know about your **UIViewController** sub class you must import its header.

So in your **AppDelegate.m** add -

```
#import "NotifyViewController.h"
```

Then assuming your **rootViewController** is of this class you can access it anywhere in your **AppDelegate.m** and send it a message using -

```
[(NotifyViewController*)self.window.rootViewController importNotificationForm];// I changed the method name slightly as I don't like to use get with a method of type void
```

Note the typecast and also please start class names with a capital letter and use camel case. Follow naming conventions for easier to read code.