# Calling methods of view controller from app delegate class

Tags: ios, observers

When my app will enter foreground, I need to call some methods of my view controller from the app delegate class. How is the best way to realise it?

I try to create a "fake" notification in "applicationWillEnterForeground" method:

```
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"test" object:nil];
```

And add observer in view controller:

```
[self addObserver: self selector:@selector(testMethod) name:@"test" object:nil];
```

Is this OK? Another method there: [Calling UIViewController method from app delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950670/calling-uiviewcontroller-method-from-app-delegate)

Which approach is better and why?

PS Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to call the method one class to another class in obj c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473878/how-to-call-the-method-one-class-to-another-class-in-obj-c)

Answer (score 0):

Quick Answer:

1. Yes, that should work with your "fake" notification
2. But why should you do so? You could let your viewController do all the things without die AppDelegate -> just call your methods, that you want to be done in the 'viewDidLoad'-method of your viewController. (I assume, your viewController is the entry point of your App)

Comment: Load-time is not the only time an app will enter foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Notification will support many destinations, whereas the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18950742/448734) only supports one viewController being told what to do.

On the other hand, calling directly through a reference is easier to understand and to debug.

I don't understand why you call it a "fake" notification - this is exactly how that call is meant to be used.